# Angular 4 & Froala : prevent empty user entry

Tags: angular, froala, angular4-forms

we are using froala editor within our angular4 app and I'm getting stuck while trying to validate the content of the editor. Basically we want to forbid the user who just type space, tab or enter character in the editor.

I tried the following code without success :

```
options: Object = {
  placeholderText: '',
  height: 300,
  charCounterMax: 3000,
  htmlAllowedEmptyTags: [],
  events : {
    'froalaEditor.blur' : function(e, editor) {
      editor.html.unwrap();
      editor.html.cleanEmptyTags();
      console.log("'" + editor.html.get() + "'");
    }
  }
}
```

Whatever I'm doing, I'm still getting

```
'<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>'
```

when the user enters twice the space bar and validate.
Is there any trim function or something similar available ?
thanks a lot

Comment: do you have a template?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `innerText` property and trim the content yourself.

### Configuration

```
const buttonConfig = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', '|', 'insertLink', '|', 'undo', 'redo'];
this.options = {
  charCounterCount: true,
  key: environment.froalaLicenseKey,
  language: 'de',
  charCounterMax: this.maxLength,
  toolbarButtons: buttonConfig,
  toolbarButtonsSM: buttonConfig,
  toolbarButtonsXS: buttonConfig,
  placeholderText: this.placeholder,
  pluginsEnabled: ['link', 'lists', 'charCounter'],
  linkAlwaysBlank: true,
  linkInsertButtons: ['linkBack'],
  linkEditButtons: ['linkOpen', 'linkEdit', 'linkRemove'],
  zIndex: 9999,
  events: {
    /*on every blur event check if the user has actually inserted content and clean if needed*/
    'froalaEditor.blur': (e: FocusEvent, editor) =>  (editor) => {
      let t = document.createElement('div');
      t.innerHTML = editor.html.get();
      let trimmedText = t.innerText.trim();
      if (!trimmedText) {
        editor.html.set('');
        editor.events.trigger('charCounter.update');
      }
    },
  },
};
```